# Allow directory in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I've got this .htaccess file installed in my folder API. It is being used to redirect all requests to the api.php script.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php?rquest=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php [QSA,NC,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php [QSA,NC,L]   
</IfModule>
```

Now, I have added some Swagger documentation for my API and need to be able to access it using this URL: `localhost/API/Swagger/ui`.  I keep getting a 404 when I try to visit that URL.

Currently setup using WAMP but will be deploying to production server as soon as I get everything tested. I can access API functions like this just fine: `localhost/API/GetMakes?year=2010`

Any ideas on what to do?

Comment: How is the "Swagger" URL routed? Is `Swagger` a physical directory? (Is `ui` a physical directory?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to prevent the URL being routed to your API (which is what I assume is triggering the 404 and not an "error" with your Swagger documentation?) is to simply include an *exception* in your `/API/.htaccess` file to prevent this particular URL being fed to your `api.php` file.

For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Do not send the following URL(s) to "api.php"
RewriteRule ^Swagger/ui - [L]

# YOUR CURRENT API RULES CONTINUE HERE...
```

So, if the requested URL *starts with* `/API/Swagger/ui` then processing stops and does not continue through the remaining mod_rewrite directives.

However, depending on how your "Swagger" URL is routed and whether `Swagger` (and `ui`) are physical subdirectories, then there may be better ways to do this.

**UPDATE:** Since it appears, from comments, that `/API/Swagger/ui` is a physical directory, then an alternative method to the above of editing the `/API/.htaccess` file, is to simply create an additional `.htaccess` file in the `/Swagger` or `/Swagger/ui` subdirectory and enable the rewrite engine. For example:

```
RewriteEngine On
```

mod_rewrite is not inherited by default, so this should have the effect of completely overriding the parent directives associated with your API. This avoids you having to edit the API `.htaccess` file.

---

*Aside:* Your current directives do seem a little strange. You first route all requests that *do not* map to physical directories or files (of size) to your API script. But then you go ahead and route all requests that do, to your API script anyway?

> **UPDATE:** I know why I'm getting a 404. The code in the API checks for a query variable called `rquest`. If it is not there, it responds with a 404

This only further backs up my comment above. The second and third rules in your `.htaccess` file don't contain the `rquest` URL param - so these would seem to just result in a 404? These directives would also prevent your "Swagger" URL from working.

Having glanced over the tutorial you linked to, it looks like the second the third rules in your `.htaccess` file should simply be removed as they don't seem to serve any real purpose (other than triggering a 404)? This would also solve your initial problem of accessing your "Swagger" documentation and would avoid having to include any "exceptions" or additional directives. In other words, reducing your `/API/.htaccess` file to the following should also "work":

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php?rquest=$1 [QSA,L]
```

However, keeping the "exception", as mentioned at the top of my answer is still *optimal*, as it prevents the unnecessary filesystem checks when accessing your "swagger" documentation.

Comment: That is the `.htaccess` that came with the code that was in the tutorial where I learned to write this REST API in PHP: http://www.tutorialsface.com/2016/02/simple-php-mysql-rest-api-sample-example-tutorial/

Comment: BTW, that still didn't work.

Comment: If that doesn't work then it may not even be your API (and these directives) that is causing your 404 "problem". It may be "something else" entirely. Is the 404 error generated by your API? And as queried above... how is the "Swagger" URL routed (or supposed to be routed)? Are `Swagger` (and `ui`) physical subdirectories?

Comment: I know why I'm getting a 404. The code in the API checks for a query variable called rquest. If it is not there, it responds with a 404, However, I have another really odd situation. When I attempt to visit `/API/Swagger/ui/index.html` without the rquest param, the page is redirected to my company's home page. I see no redirections to my company URL in my .htaccess nor in my httpd.conf. It doesn't matter if my WAMP server is running or not, go figure. My hosts file does not have a redirect for localhost,either. Any ideas on that one?

Comment: After some more testing, it seems that Google Chrome is the culprit, here. I tried it in Edge and IE and it works. Why would Chrome redirect me?

Comment: In that case, the code in my answer should have prevented the 404 you mentioned in the question. If it "still didn't work" then you were getting a different error/problem. If it's only redirecting on Chrome then that sounds like browser caching issue. If you get a redirect without he webserver running(!) then it can only be client-side (meta refresh or JavaScript) or browser cache. Checking the network traffic will rule out the former. If you disable the webserver then presumably you are accessing the site via a local filesystem path?!

Comment: I had to place my SwaggerUI directory one above my API for it to work correctly. I'm abandoning the effort to put it in the same directory. Thanks for looking at this.

Comment: I'm revisiting this due to questions from my devop. If I include the line that you suggested above, I am getting this in my apache access log: `::1 - - [04/Jun/2018:11:55:58 -0500] "GET /API/Swagger/ui HTTP/1.1" 301 318` followed by `::1 - - [04/Jun/2018:11:55:58 -0500] "GET /API/Swagger/ui/ HTTP/1.1" 302 -` I'm getting TEN of these per attempt.

Comment: Ah, it would seem `/ui` is a physical directory after all. (And yes you did mention `/API/Swagger/ui/index.html` in a comment above.) So, the URL you are requesting is really `/API/Swagger/ui/` (with a trailing slash) - mod_dir automatically appends the slash with a 301 redirect. This then won't match the exception and it will indeed be routed through the API. It would seem you need an exception for _any URL_ that _starts_ `/API/Swagger/ui`, not just the URL `/API/Swagger/ui` as mentioned in your question. You need to remove the `$` from the end of the URL _pattern_. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Yep, that was it. I thought I tried that one, too but I guess not. Have a great day and thanks.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. I've just made some additional comments in my answer, having looked at the tutorial you linked to. It looks like you could simplify this further, as the second and third `RewriteRule` directives in your API `.htaccess` file look superfluous.

Comment: "The second and third rules in your .htaccess file don't contain the rquest URL param - so these would seem to just result in a 404? These directives would also prevent your "Swagger" URL from working."   Well, the api handles if there is an rquest param. It throws a 302 and redirects to our home page if there is no rquest param.